# Import JS file into Next JS - Getting reference error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, codemirror

I'm getting the following error when trying to import a js file in my Next JS project.

**Error:**
***ReferenceError: navigator is not defined***

Here is the component I'm using to insert the file. I need it for Codemirror to render python out properly but the component only works if I remove the **mode/python/python.js** import

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { UnControlled as CodeMirror } from "react-codemirror2";
// import "../node_modules/codemirror/mode/python/python.js";
import "../node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css";
import "../node_modules/codemirror/theme/material.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

const CodeContainer = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  left: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1;
`;

const Code = () => (
  <CodeContainer>
    <CodeMirror
      value="<h1>Hello World</h1>"
      options={{
        mode: "python",
        theme: "material",
        lineNumbers: true
      }}
      onChange={(editor, data, value) => {}}
    />
  </CodeContainer>
);

export default Code;
```

Comment: Try this `require("codemirror/mode/python/python")`

Comment: You should dynamically import the `Code` component wherever it's used using [`next/dynamic`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) with `{ ssr: false }`.

Answer (score 0):

You should import python-mode dynamically like this:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
 const dynamicPython= dynamic(() =>import("codemirror/mode/python/python.js"),{
     ssr:false,
 });
```

Comment: [`next/dynamic`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) only works for React component, which `/codemirror/mode/python/python.js` is not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the `import('codemirror/mode/python/python.js').then((module) => { /* Do something if needed */ });` block, you can perform any additional actions or configurations that are necessary for the imported module. However, in most cases, you may not need to do anything specific, and the import itself will take care of setting up the CodeMirror Python mode.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { UnControlled as CodeMirror } from 'react-codemirror2';
import '../node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import '../node_modules/codemirror/theme/material.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const CodeContainer = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  left: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1;
`;

const Code = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Dynamically import the Python mode only on the client side
    import('../node_modules/codemirror/mode/python/python.js').then((module) => {
      // You can perform additional actions here if needed
      // For example, you can log something to the console
      console.log('Python mode has been loaded:', module);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <CodeContainer>
      <CodeMirror
        value="<h1>Hello World</h1>"
        options={{
          mode: 'python',
          theme: 'material',
          lineNumbers: true,
        }}
        onChange={(editor, data, value) => {
          // Handle CodeMirror change event if needed
        }}
      />
    </CodeContainer>
  );
};

export default Code;
```

Hope this will help you get your desired output; otherwise, It'll help you to identify the exact issue.